# System-wide ${PATH} for non-login shells (in Debian)

Tags: linux, debian, shell, path

I saw that similar questions were already asked, but I think the problem still exists.

I did a standard thing, added a software to the `/opt/` directory. Say, Go. `/opt/go` is the main directory and `/opt/go/bin` is the place where the binaries are.

The problem: How to extend system-wide `$PATH` for **non-login** shells. After a user logs in and click on a terminal icon, a non-login shell starts. At this point user's `PATH` should contain Go binaries.

I tried:

- `/etc/profile.d/` Does not work, because it is not read by non-login shells.
- `/etc/environment.d` Cannot use variables, so `PATH="${PATH}:/opt/go/bin"` does not work. And I will have much more paths to add. What about root's different `PATH`?
- `/etc/login.defs` Is not read when users are in LDAP or for some other reason.

Weird or clumsy solutions that might work partially:

- modifying a sheel `.rc` global file, like `bash.bashrc`, but it is kinda wrong and will not survive updates. A `.d/*` directories are good solutions for these problems. And there are many shells.
- using `/etc/environment.d/` with the `PATH` set without previously set `PATH` value from other places: `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:...`. What about root's different `PATH`?
- symlinking binaries in the `/usr/local/bin`, but with dozens of binaries this is not a pleasant thing.

And finally, **the only thing that worked**:

- using `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` directory. I simply added the same file that would be placed in the `/etc/profile.d/` directory and the `PATH` was correctly set for the GUI environment. And there is no conflict with TTY, which would be set by `/etc/profile.d/`.

Why did I wrote that the problem still persists in the first place? Because `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` seems like a weird place to do this. Is there really no better/right way to do this? An administrator setting a system-wide `PATH` for his users seems a common thing to do :) Or am I really missing an obvious solution here?

Kind Regards
Kamil

Comment: A counter question: Given that users have control over their own shell initialization files for whatever shell they decide to use, wouldn't it be easier for the individuals that wanted to use software from `/opt` to modify their own shell files, than it would be for them to _remove_ an element from `PATH` if they are not interested in the `/opt` software, or than it would be for you to cover all possible corner cases of where `PATH` may possibly be set or reset?

Comment: I would say no: I run a computer laboratory at a University and lecturers and students simply expect some software to be in the `PATH`. And with several hundreds of them It would be wrong to tell each one to set their own `PATH`, some would not know how to do this, etc. And setting a `PATH` is an administrator's job ususally.

Comment: Isn't `PATH` exported by default? So that setting it in the login shell would be enough. How would any process that launches child processes get the correct `PATH` if it wasn't exported, and only came from the shell's initialization files? (Bash would set a builtin default `PATH` for scripts though, so stuff in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` would still work.) `/etc/environment` might set it too, if nothing else. But of course if the X session starts through something that doesn't run `pam_env`, or a login shell, then you wouldn't get it from there. Anyway, getting it in the environment is what I'd do.